# Li tags in Navigation Bar is not Responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a navigation bar and when I make the screen size smaller, the list items overlap into the left of the navigation where there is the logo instead of keeping to their positions. Here is the HTML code:

```
<header>

<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="navbar-header">
  <button class="navbar-toggle" data-target="navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">                        
    <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar">  </span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
    <img id="indexlogo" width="20%" alt="logo" src="img/siluxLogo1.png" >
   </a>
 </div>
 <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">                        

  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" >                           
   <li >                                
    <a>hello and welcome</a>
   </li>
   <li >
    <a id="date"></a>  <!-- JS which displays date and year -->
   </li>                            
   <li >                             
    <a id="feed"></a>  <!-- RSS feed ticker -->
   </li>
   <li class="active">
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="about.html">About Us</a>
   </li>                          
   <li>
    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>                  
</div>
</div>
</header><!-- end header -->
```

Can someone please point out where I am going wrong or what I am missing. I have the viewport meta tag and the other parts of the page are responsive.

Answer (score 0):

adding an id just before the unordered list would also fix it.

`<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">...</div>`

and then set `data-target="#navbar"`

also, you should add this class to your button. `class="collapsed"`

**Here is an example from my own site, which works**

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
```

You also don't need `container-fluid`

`// DROP IN THIS AND TELL ME IF IT WORKS`

```
<!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top mega navbar-trans navbar-fw">
        <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>

        <!-- Navbar Links -->
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse page-scroll navbar-right">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#home">Home<span class="sr-only"></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About<span class="sr-only"></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#services">Services<span class="sr-only"></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio<span class="sr-only"></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#pricing">Pricing<span class="sr-only"></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact<span class="sr-only"></span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Can you verify your loading in `jquery` and `bootstrap.js`, as I know I personally have forgotten to do this once or twice.

Comment: Also, fairly major problem. The first div after the `<header>` should be a `<nav>` not a `div`. 

So like this

`<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">`

Comment: is it not catered for by the class "navbar"? But i did change it and its still not responsive.

Comment: It is, but lets meet default usage. Can you confirm you are loading in all bootstrap files, including Jquery?

Comment: Confirmed @Pipskweak and I am using the <nav> now

Comment: @dominicbure let me know if what I just added to my parent answer works on your end.

Answer (score 0):

Coppy code below and paste your editor.
You try it work fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"> </script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>
</head>
<body>
<header>
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="navbar-header">
  <button class="navbar-toggle" data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">                        
  <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar">  </span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
 <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
  <img id="indexlogo" width="20%" alt="logo" src="img/siluxLogo1.png" >
 </a>
 </div>
 <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">                        

 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" >                           
  <li >                                
  <a>hello and welcome</a>
  </li>
  <li >
 <a id="date"></a>  <!-- JS which displays date and year -->
 </li>                            
 <li >                             
 <a id="feed"></a>  <!-- RSS feed ticker -->
 </li>
 <li class="active">
 <a href="index.html">Home</a>
 </li>
 <li>
 <a href="about.html">About Us</a>
 </li>                          
 <li>
 <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
 </li>
 </ul>
 </div>                  
 </div>
 </div>
 </header><!-- end header -->
 </body>
 </html>
```